# WooCommerce hierarchical products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

i have 2 products in my WooCommerce Store.
My first product is a bundled product and my second product should be a child from the first product.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to create hierarchical products with WooCommerce.
I need this for my slug structure http://mywebsite.com/products/first-article/second-article

When i change in the file (wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-post-types.php) the register_post_type args to hierarchical = true, then nothing happen.

Has anyone ever had the same problem?
How can i solve this with WooCommerce hooks?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'wc_register_post_type_product_args');
function wc_register_post_type_product_args($args)
{
    $args['hierarchical'] = true;
    $args['supports'][] = 'page-attributes';

    return $args;
}
```